# I create two entities during cdm, but they doesn't exist?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So .. i create two entities from console

[image]

Then i type `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` and get "No metadata Classes to process. (i already tried everything who found)

Then try to debug with `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info` and get this:

[image]

Any ideas?

> parameters.yml:

[image]

> config.yml:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us doctrine configuration (probably in `config.yml`)?

Comment: parameters.yml u mean ?

Comment: No, but `config.yml` should be in the same directory. [In doctrine bundle config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#full-default-configuration) you need `auto_mapping: true` or [custom mapping](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle)

Comment: See the picture above

Comment: Looks good. Did you try to clean cache first?

Comment: Can you show your entities?

Comment: Yeah ..every time type "php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod" before to try. @iillexial What part from entities u want to see ?

Comment: Article Entity : https://pastebin.com/Sk9UY8z7
User Entity: https://pastebin.com/v6dpfJQR

Comment: This is common issue in doctrine. I have described reasons in my answer which was deleted by @Martijn Pieters without any understanding...